# Insert values from buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, innerhtml

I am creating an order form. If I have 2 sets of buttons for Color and Size, how do I insert the value of the selected button into another element?

For example, you should be able to choose the Color and Size , in any order, and have it append to the Product Name, so in the summary, it will say

```
Product Name, [Size] , [Color]
```

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1np30t4y/1/). Right now I have it to where you can select only 1 of each Size or Color and the active class is added to that choice. The problem I have when I am trying to add it to the summary is that it is duplicating and I am not sure how to validate it so that it will not.

Comment: What do you want for the end result? ``Incredibles T-Shirt - Green,Small``,``Incredibles T-Shirt - Green - Small``

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO The way it is displayed isn't that important. Commas or Dashes are fine, so long as the data is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for a different solution, adding an array that will store the values and a function that can be call to update the summary

```
        let values = [item[0].innerHTML,'',''];

function updateSummary(){
    item[1].innerHTML = values.join(' ');
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1np30t4y/29/)
Hope this helps :)

```js
var size = document.getElementById('size');
var sizeBtns = size.getElementsByClassName('size-button');


for (var i = 0; i < sizeBtns.length; i++) {
    sizeBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var btnElements = sizeBtns[0];
        while(btnElements){
            if(btnElements.tagName === "BUTTON"){
                btnElements.classList.remove("size-active");
            }
            btnElements = btnElements.nextSibling;
        }

        this.classList.add("size-active");

          var sizeSelected = size.getElementsByClassName('size-active')[0].value;


        values[1] = sizeSelected;
        updateSummary();


    });
}

var color = document.getElementById('color');
var colorBtns = color.getElementsByClassName('color-button');

for (var c = 0; c < colorBtns.length; c++) {
    colorBtns[c].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var btnElements = colorBtns[0];
        while(btnElements){
            if(btnElements.tagName === "BUTTON"){
                btnElements.classList.remove("color-active");
            }
            btnElements = btnElements.nextSibling;
        }

        this.classList.add("color-active");

        var colorSelected = color.getElementsByClassName('color-active')[0].value;

    values[2] = colorSelected;
        updateSummary();

    });
}

var item = document.getElementsByClassName('product-item');

  
    item[0].innerHTML = "Incredibles T-Shirt";
    item[1].innerHTML = item[0].innerHTML;
  let values = [item[0].innerHTML,'',''];


function updateSummary(){
 item[1].innerHTML = values.join(' ');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  body button {
    cursor: pointer; }

div {
  display: flex;
  width: 85%; }

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px grey; }

#price {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5%; }

h1 {
  text-align: center; }

h2 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: fit-content; }

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 5%; }

.order-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: whitesmoke; }
  .order-form:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: white; }

.order-form:nth-child(3) {
  display: block; }
  .order-form:nth-child(3) p {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto; }

#summary {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%; }
  #summary p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 48%; }

#product {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  #product img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%; }

#size {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; }
  #size button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem; }

#color {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; }
  #color button {
    width: 65px;
    height: 30px;
    color: white; }
  #color button:nth-child(1) {
    background: red; }
  #color button:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue; }
  #color button:nth-child(3) {
    background: green; }
  #color button:nth-child(4) {
    background: black; }

form {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; }
  form input, form select {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5px; }
  form input:nth-child(10) {
    width: 50%; }
  form select:nth-child(12) {
    width: 50%; }
  form input:nth-child(14) {
    width: 50%; }
  form select:nth-child(16) {
    width: 50%; }

#complete-order {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: block; }

.size-active {
  background: gold; }

.color-active {
  border: 3px solid gold; }

label.required::before, p.required::before {
  content: '*';
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: red; }

p.required {
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Order Form</h1>
<div id="container">

<div class="order-form">

    <h2 class="product-item"></h2>

    <div id="product">
    <img src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/file_0da4ff14.jpeg?width=1200&region=0%2C0%2C2000%2C2000" alt="Incredibles T-Shirt ">
    </div>

    <h3 id="price">$20.00</h3>

    <h3>Select a Size</h3>
    <div id="size">
        <button class="size-button" type="button" value="Small">S</button>
        <button class="size-button" type="button" value="Medium">M</button>
        <button class="size-button" type="button" value="Large">L</button>
    </div>

    <h3>Select a Color</h3>
    <div id="color">
        <button class="color-button" type="button" value="Red">Red</button>
        <button class="color-button" type="button" value="Blue">Blue</button>
        <button class="color-button" type="button" value="Green">Green</button>
        <button class="color-button" type="button" value="Black">Black</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="order-form">
<h2>Shipping Details</h2>
    <form id="shipping-details">
        <p class="required"> = required fields</p>
        <label for="fullname" class="required">Full Name</label>
        <input id="fullname" type="text"/>

        <label for="email" class="required">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email"/>

        <label for="address" class="required">Address</label>
        <input id="address" type="text"/>

        <label for="address2">Address 2</label>
        <input id="address2" type="text"/>

        <label for="city" class="required">City</label>
        <input id="city" type="text"/>

        <label for="state" class="required">State</label>
        <select id="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>

        <label for="zip"class="required">Zip</label>
        <input id="zip" type="text"/>

        <label for="country" class="required">Country</label>
        <select id="country">
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
            <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
            <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
            <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
            <option value="TD">Chad</option>
            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
            <option value="CN">China</option>
            <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
            <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
            <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
            <option value="CG">Congo</option>
            <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
            <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
            <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
            <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
            <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
            <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
            <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
            <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
            <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IN">India</option>
            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
            <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
            <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
            <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
            <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
            <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
            <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
            <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
            <option value="LY">Libya</option>
            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MO">Macao</option>
            <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
            <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="NE">Niger</option>
            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="NU">Niue</option>
            <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
            <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
            <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
            <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
            <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
            <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
            <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
            <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
            <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
            <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
            <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
            <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
            <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
            <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
            <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
            <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
            <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
            <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
            <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
            <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
            <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
            <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
            <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
            <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
            <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
            <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
            <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>


    </form>
</div>

<div class="order-form">
<h2>Order Summary</h2>
    <div id="summary">
    <p class="product-item"></p>
    <p>$20.00</p>
    <p>Shipping</p>
    <p>Free</p>
    <p>Total</p>
    <p>$20.00</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Shipping Address</h3>
    <address>
        <p>Sarah Smith</p>
        <p>23412 S. University Ave.</p>
        <p>Winter Park, FL 32792</p>
    </address>
    <button type=submit id="complete-order">Place Order</button>
</div>


</div>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: like this one as well, thank you :) , formats a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have updated your code so that color and size are in individual spans and you only update those, instead of the whole text.
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1np30t4y/13/)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < sizeBtns.length; i++) {
   // existing code .. 

          var sizeSelected = size.getElementsByClassName('size-active')[0].value;
          document.querySelector("span.size").innerText = sizeSelected;

    });
}

for (var c = 0; c < colorBtns.length; c++) {
    colorBtns[c].addEventListener("click", function() {

        // existing code .. 
        var colorSelected = color.getElementsByClassName('color-active')[0].value;

        document.querySelector("span.color").innerText = colorSelected;

    });
}
```

```html
<!-- existing code ... -->

<div class="order-form">
<h2>Order Summary</h2>
    <div id="summary">
    <p class="product-item"></p>
    <span class="size"></span>
    <span class="color"></span>
    <p>$20.00</p>
    <p>Shipping</p>
    <p>Free</p>
    <p>Total</p>
    <p>$20.00</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Shipping Address</h3>
    <address>
        <p>Sarah Smith</p>
        <p>23412 S. University Ave.</p>
        <p>Winter Park, FL 32792</p>
    </address>
    <button type=submit id="complete-order">Place Order</button>
</div>


</div>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can do with this further.